# html-to-react: How can I replace all 'img' elements with a React component while preserving styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This question is in relation to [html-to-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react) library.

Imagine I have the following *html string*:

`'<div>
   <img src="test.png" style="width: 100px;"/>
   <img src="test2.png" style="margin: 0px 4px;"/>
</div>'`

Typically I would parse this as follows:

```
import {Parser} from 'html-to-react'
const reactElement = Parser.parse(htmlString);
```

This will produce a React element with a `div` and 2 nested `img` elements as its children.

---

How can I instead parse this string so that each `img` is replaced with a custom `Image` component, preserving the original props/attributes of the `img` (including styles)?

e.g. the resulting react element would have the following children:

`<div>
  <Image src="test.png" style={{width: 100}}/>
  <Image src="test2.png" style={{margin: "0px 4px"}}/>
</div>`

Help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can attain that by doing the following,

```
Parser(htmlString, {
  replace: (domNode) => {
    if (domNode.name === "img") {
      return <Image src={domNode.attribs.src} style={{ width: 100 }} />;
    }
  },
});
```

This doesnt fully solve your problem as I can see you need two different style for two image tags, but playing around with this may get you a solution.

Answer (score -1):

please try this:

```
const { Parser } = require('html-to-react');

const htmlString = '<div>
    <img src="test.png" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <img src="test2.png" style="margin: 0px 4px;"/>
</div>'; 

const reactComponent = Parser.parseWithInstructions(
    htmlString,() {
        return true;
    },[
        {replaceChildren: true}
    ]
);
```

Comment: Hi @Aman, can you describe what this code snippet does? I don't see where the `img` elements are being replaced by `Image` elements. It's possible I didn't communicate my problem well enough earlier (I've added some extra details to OP now)